# How do I create a chartjs bar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The following code is supposed to create a new bar chart but I'm getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined" which points to the first line (var chart = new Chart etc)

```
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart1"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Num incidents",
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    data: [89,57,25,28]
                }],
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
```

I have a html file with the following:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>

<div class="column">
  <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Do i need to include the chartjs api in the js file as well? 

Or do i need to call the chart somewhere in my js file?

Comment: Are you loading your `Chart.min.js` before you call the `new Chart` method ?

Comment: I'm not sure since i got a bunch of the code from a colleague. It could indeed be the order of files loaded in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. It must be just the order.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="column">
          <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart1"), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Num incidents",
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        data: [89,57,25,28]
                    }],
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or play here: https://jsfiddle.net/2d9kfegj/2/

Answer (score 0):

Inside your html file:

```
<script src="myJavascript.js"> </script>
```

The problem is that you don't include your js file in your html. Make sure you include your js file at the end of your html like:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js">
    </script>

</head>

<div class="column">
    <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="myJavascript.js"></script>
```

After that it will work just fine. You need to load your page first so your JS knows where to put the chart that is created.

In jquery you can use `document.ready` function but since you don't have a jquery tag i will avoid to mention to put a listener for page ready and suggest to just put it in the end for your ease.

Comment: Forgive me for being unclear. I have included js in my html but this code is for a company so i'm a little wary of posting too much code. It is however possible that my problem lies in the order in which the files are loaded. Looking into it now.

Comment: Below code worked fine for me but if i put the including script anywhere else it breaks as well cause the dom is not loaded when i request the JS to run. Did you try my appoach to include it in the end?

Comment: That code worked for me as well. The problem does seem to be the order in which files are loaded. I am accepting Nicky's answer as its the most usable for anyone seeing this.